# Можно ли поставить условие "if" на метод или событие?

Tags: c#

Можно ли поставить условие "if" на методы или событие? То есть если код вызван методом/событием 1, тогда используем одни смещения в коде, если вызван методом/событием 2, тогда используем другие смещения. И таких 10 условий.
Покажу на примере:

```
     unsafe void PatchFilesLevel5()
    {
        long[] offsets = { 0x2B7, 0x2B7 + 0xB8, 0x2B7 + 0x170 }; /* если код вызван 
событием buttonPatchAllLevelM_Click, тогда в этой строке 
используются смещения:  long[] offsets = { 0x2B7, 0x2B7 + 0xB8, 0x2B7 + 0x170 };

//Если код вызван событием buttonPatchAllLevelP_Click, тогда в этой строке 
используются смещения:  long[] offsets = { 0x2B8, 0x2B8 + 0xB8, 0x2B8 + 0x170 };

// Если код вызван событием buttonPatchAllLevelMPerc_Click, тогда в этой строке
 используются смещения:  long[] offsets = { 0x2B9, 0x2B9 + 0xB8, 0x2B9 + 0x170 };
и т.д. Всего 10 таких условий*/
        ...
        decimal mulitplyBy = numericUpDownAll.Value; 
        foreach (string fileName in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Application.StartupPath + @"\unpacked2", "scene*"))
        {
            Match m = ...
            if ...
            {
                int p = ...
                if ((p >= 9 ...
                {
                    using (var fstream = new FileStream...
                    {
                        foreach (long offset in offsets)
                        {
                            if (offset + 4 < fstream.Length)
                            {
                                fstream.P...
                                fstream.R...

                                int n = (int)(mulitplyBy * BitConverter.ToInt32(buf4, 0)); 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Можно ли показать как эти условия вставить в этот код?

Comment: передавать в метод параметр, который бы указывал откуда его вызвали. Далее ставим обычные ифы: `if (callFrom == "CallFromEvent")` - что-то типа того

Comment: В вашем случае лучше применять [switch case](https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level3/3_14.php).

Comment: А можно более подробно? Как для новичка, с примерами кода. Там такие условия нужны: если код вызван 
событием buttonPatchAllLevelM_Click, тогда в этой строке 
используются смещения:  long[] offsets = { 0x2B7, 0x2B7 + 0xB8, 0x2B7 + 0x170 };

//Если код вызван событием buttonPatchAllLevelP_Click, тогда в этой строке 
используются смещения:  long[] offsets = { 0x2B8, 0x2B8 + 0xB8, 0x2B8 + 0x170 };

// Если код вызван событием buttonPatchAllLevelMPerc_Click, тогда в этой строке
 используются смещения:  long[] offsets = { 0x2B9, 0x2B9 + 0xB8, 0x2B9 + 0x170 };
и т.д. Всего 10 таких условий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать даже без всяких проверок.

- Нужно добавить методу PatchFilesLevel5 параметр offsets типа long
  `unsafe void PatchFilesLevel5(long[] offsets)`(локальную переменную offsets конечно нужно удалить)
- В обработчике события закидывать в метод в виде аргумента нужные смещения
  `buttonPatchAllLevelM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  PatchFilesLevel5(new long[]{ 0x2B7, 0x2B7 + 0xB8, 0x2B7 + 0x170 });
  }`

Comment: Спасибо большое за подсказку. А можно также сделать в строке 

`decimal mulitplyBy = numericUpDownAll.Value;`  вместо numericUpDownAll.Value;  использовать при нажатии другой кнопки numericUpDown222.Value; при нажатии третей кнопки numericUpDown333.Value;